# Retrieve coin base price (or quantity) from transaction data using BscScan APIs

Tags: api, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi, bscscan

I'm trying to write an app to track my gains/losses for tax purposes based on the swaps I've made using Bscscan APIs. I can easily retrieve all the swaps I've made using one of BscScan "accounts" module api endpoint (**Get a list of 'BEP-20 Token Transfer Events' by Address** to be exact). Here's an example of the body response:

```html
{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": [{
      "blockNumber": "2304192",
      "timeStamp": "1605585978",
      "hash": "0x7a5abf86c82d3f97a40dd841a9f2089fbe3ac1332157c01bd1a1d89f575c45fc",
      "nonce": "57",
      "blockHash": "0x703438fd8ba435996895a6b9b711934cc590c3e9297a7066419aa88dd9d83acc",
      "from": "0x641414e2a04c8f8ebbf49ed47cc87dccba42bf07",
      "contractAddress": "0xc9849e6fdb743d08faee3e34dd2d1bc69ea11a51",
      "to": "0x7bb89460599dbf32ee3aa50798bbceae2a5f7f6a",
      "value": "27605634758857128698365",
      "tokenName": "Bunny Token",
      "tokenSymbol": "BUNNY",
      "tokenDecimal": "18",
      "transactionIndex": "2",
      "gas": "5000000",
      "gasPrice": "20000000000",
      "gasUsed": "2312130",
      "cumulativeGasUsed": "2475576",
      "input": "deprecated",
      "confirmations": "8172919"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the value input ("value": "27605634758857128698365") gives the value in the underlying coin "currency" - in this case "Bunny Token" - but without knowing the quantity of that coin bought, I can't determine the cost basis of that transaction. I've looked at other bscscan APIs but I couldn't find any that would could help me retrieve the price of the coin for a given transaction.

Does anyone know if there's a way to retrieve the price of a coin (or the quantity bought) based on the transaction data using bsccan api?

TIA